# Connecting WIFI on Virtual BOX

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I have installed VIRTUAL BOX on ubuntu. and this virtual box, i have installed Android Marshmallow. i tried to connect to wifi on android, but no connection appears. i tried to many tutorials, not getting this yet

my current network setting this, check the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: It'll inevitably be becasue you're presenting the guest OS (Android) with the suitable NIC. it won't understand what the Intel card is. Additionally, the intel card you've presented is a LAN card. You'll need to either change the NIC presented to the guest OS or, if you do get the Intel card working with local addresses, bridge the adapter to your wireless card so you can get Internet... i think you'll need to find more tutorials on getting Android working with VirtualBox network interfaces aqnd which ones are compatible.

Comment: How to change NIC presented to the guest OS?

Comment: Change the "adapter type".  You need to select an adapter that is supported by Android.